# After modifying xml files, do I have to always restart the server?

Tags: xml, struts2

I'm using eclipse(galileo) and struts2 framework and tiles.

It seems that modifying xml files(struts.xml, tiles-config.xml, etc) is not affected until I restart the server.

It is very annoying and it takes more time. Is there any way not to restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly, you don't have to restart the entire server, just the application itself.  But to answer your question more directly, the configuration files (by default at any rate) are just read on startup and the values are held for the life of the application.

For Tiles you might try [this](http://tiles.apache.org/2.1/framework/config-reference.html#org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.LocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.CHECK_REFRESH) init parameter, but I've not tried it personally, so I can't vouch for it.

For Struts, try setting devMode ([Link](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/devmode.html)) to true.

`<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />`

For changes to web.xml, and others, I think there's a setting at the application server level to control that, but I doubt that it's standard across all application servers.

Comment: Thank you. I changed devMode true. But for the tiles, I don't know where to change that init param.

Comment: From the documentation, you set it as a context param in the web.xml file.

Comment: Deckard - did you get this to work with Tiles?  auto-reload tiles definitions when the xml file changes?  If so, would you be willing to share details on how you did it?